# Product of two rotations

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, rotations, isometry, reflection

I apologize to anyone I wasted his/her time by this trivial question.

I have difficulty understanding how the product of two rotations can be a rotation as well.

Or in other words is the product of 4 reflections a rotation **(using isometry rule of rotation=2 non-parallel reflections)** iff the mirrors/reflective lines intersect at one point(center)?

I would greatly appreciate any sort of explanation or hints about this.

Comment: Do you at least believe that this is true in two dimensions?

Comment: Also, could you prove that three such consecutive reflections are achievable by a single one?

Comment: In what dimension are you operating? Is this for 2d, 3d or arbitrary dimension? Would you feel comfortable with an argument from linear algebra, speaking about matrices and vectors and so on, or would you rather stick to a purely geometric language? How do you think about a rotation? Something with a center, a rotation angle and perhaps an rotation axis direction in dimenions $>2$, or rather as a combination of reflections?

Comment: @MvG arbitrary dimension, I would prefer a geometric language, as I am trying to make  the geometric proof for it.